# php key giveaway script doesnt work

Tags: php

i am trying to make a key giveaway script to give a key away whenever someone enter his mail in the input. i came pretty far but now i have 1 problem, when it send the mail i should send you the key but it doesnt, it just only send the text "your code is:"

it send the key in the "$message" whenever its sends it it should run the function dispres and grab the key out of the database.

can someone see the what the problem is?

```
<?php
     //fill in mail

    echo "
    <form method='post' action=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . ">
        Email: <input name='email'></input><br>
        <input type='submit' value='Get your key' name='submit'> </input><br><br>
    </form>";

        if(empty($_POST["email"]))
        {
            echo "Please enter an email adress.";
        }
        else{

            //mail key to input mail
            $to      = $_POST["email"];
            $subject = 'TEST';
            $message = 'Your code is:' . dispres();
            $headers = 'niks';

            mail($to, $subject, $message);

            echo "Your code has been sent to your email: " . $_POST["email"] . " \r";
            echo dispres();
        }



    function dispres(){

    //database connect
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pwd = 'password';

    $database = 'keys';
    $table = 'keytest';

    if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
        die("Can't connect to database");

    if (!mysql_select_db($database))
        die("Can't select database");


    //grab random key from database

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} order by RAND() LIMIT 1");

    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    $result = implode('|',$row);


    echo $result;






    //delete key from database

    //mysqli_query("DELETE FROM keytest WHERE name='$cell1'");

    //remember ip adress for 1 use only
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: There should be a `return $result;` at the end of the dispres() function.

Comment: that fixed it but now i get a other key in the mail then is displayed on the site. anything for that?

Comment: Just call dispres() once (=1 key) and store the key in a variable, i.e., `$key = dispres();` ... `$message = 'Your code is:' . $key;` ... `echo $key;`.

Comment: Could you implement this in the my code and paste it? I am not very good in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a return statement to the dispres() function.
2. Call dispres() only once to obtain only a single key per user.

```
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    echo "Please enter an email adress.";
} else {
    // get key from database
    $key = dispres();

    //mail key to input mail
    $to      = $_POST["email"];
    $subject = 'TEST';
    $message = 'Your code is:' . $key;
    $headers = 'niks';

    mail($to, $subject, $message);

    echo "Your code has been sent to your email: " . $_POST["email"] . " \r";
    echo $key;
}

function dispres() {
    // ...

    // replace:
    // echo $result;
    // by:
    return $result;
}
```